# How to copy content from a page in a html tag and put that in a database

Tags: php, html, curl

I have been searching for days now to find a script or other solution that could help me find specific information from companies. I want to collect the name, city, and province (dutch) of each company. Nothing more.

At first I was thinking I could curl the page and then use "if...then".
I found a script to get the page.
Now I want to get information that is between specific HTML tags.

Is that possible?
Could someone please tell me were to look? In what direction?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
I use the following code to get the HTML page:

```
 function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$returned_content = get_data('http://www.detelefoongids.nl/rijschool/zuid-holland/3-1/?what=rijschool&where=Zuid+Holland&page=2&splitType=regular&sortBy=relevance&collapsing=true&mostDominantHeading=Auto-rijscholen');

echo $returned_content;
```

The URL contains information I want to have. As you can see, for example, the name of the company (lets use the first result: Dubbeldam BV Autorijschool Piet
And the location (cityname): Barendrecht  These two I want to get in the database.

But how?

Comment: Achieve this by using **DOM** http://www.php.net/book.dom

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to use the **preg_match()** and **preg_match_all()** to parse the required fields from the html document using regex. For example:

```
$html = '<b>Name: </b><div id="xyz">alex</div>';
preg_match('|<b>Name:\s*</b><div id="xyz">(.*?)</div>|', $html, $m);
print "Name: $m[1]";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. please feel free to edit / tune the script :)

I fixed it with the SIMPLE DOM

```
$adres = 'http://www.izee.nl';
    require_once 'simple_html_dom.php'; //file SIMPLE HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html($adres); //the address I want to "strip"

// code from the Simple HTML DOM
foreach($html->find('div.infoData') as $school) {
$item['schoolnaam'] = $school->find('h4/a[itemprop=name]', 0)->plaintext;
$item['schoolplace'] = $school->find('span.city', 0)->plaintext;
$scholen[] = $item;


$data = array_filter($scholen);
//connection with de database   
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_schools");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo 'There is something really bad going on...: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}
//put stripped info in the dabatse

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl_scholen (schoolnamen,schoolplaces) VALUES('$item[schoolnaam]', '$item[schoolplace]')");    

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tbl_scholen set schoolnamen = TRIM(schoolnaam);");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tbl_scholen set schoolplaces = TRIM(schoolplace);");
}
print_r($scholen);
```